# Excel VBA - how to select column AND row of active cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been struggling with VBA code that selects entire row and column of active cell. I tried many codes, but all of them failed. I don't want to make any changes to range, I need to just select it.

How selection after macro should look like:
[Selected column and row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amAzD.png)

Last version of code I came up with, still not working. Any ideas how to achieve it or fix it?

```
Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()

    Dim Column As range
       Set Column = ActiveCell.EntireColumn
    Dim Row As range
       Set Row = ActiveCell.EntireRow
    Dim rng As range
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = Union(.range(Column), .range(Row))
    End With
    
  rng.Select

    Unload Me
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but this can done simply with:

```
With ActiveCell
    Union(.EntireRow, .EntireColumn).Select
End With
```

Or just a one-liner:

```
Union(ActiveCell.EntireRow, ActiveCell.EntireColumn).Select
```

Comment: I cannot even express how grateful I am, thank you! It looks so easy now and I spend 4h trying to do it.

Comment: You're welcome. Part of the learning is the struggle I'd say. The fact you continued on is laudable. Happy coding!